# Swagger is throwing 500 when i have parameters that derives from some base class

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

When I have action that has parameters which derives from some base class, on launching the app Swagger is throwing 500 error.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("documents/generate")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(DocGenWorkflowAsyncResponse), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(DocGenWorkflowAsyncResponse), StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(HttpResponse), StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(HttpResponse), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[Trace("Generate Document Action")]
public Task<IActionResult> Generate(MergeRequest mergeRequest)
{
    return _triggerDocumentWorkflowAdapter.TriggerWorkflow(mergeRequest);
}
```

**MergeRequest**

```
public class MergeRequest : BaseRequest { }

public abstract class BaseRequest {}
```

**Swagger Setup**

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(swaggerGenOptions =>
{
                swaggerGenOptions.SwaggerDoc(
                    ServiceInfo.Version,
                    new OpenApiInfo
                    {
                        Title = ServiceInfo.Name,
                        Version = ServiceInfo.Version
                    });

                var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()!.GetName().Name}.xml";
                var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);

                swaggerGenOptions.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath, includeControllerXmlComments: true);
});
```

Exception:

{"SeverityText":"Error","Message":"Connection id \u00220HMRUS3P495NL\u0022, Request id \u00220HMRUS3P495NL:00000005\u0022: An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.","ClassName":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel","Attributes":{"ExceptionType":"Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException","ExceptionMessage":"Failed to generate Operation for action - DocumentDove.Web.Controllers.DocumentsController.Generate (DocumentDove.Web). See inner exception","ExceptionStackTrace":"   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateOperation(ApiDescription apiDescription, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)\r\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GenerateOperations(IEnumerable\u00601 apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)\r\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GeneratePaths(IEnumerable\u00601 apiDescriptions, SchemaRepository schemaRepository)\r\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwaggerDocumentWithoutFilters(String documentName, String host, String basePath)\r\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwaggerAsync(String documentName, String host, String basePath)\r\n   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)\r\n   at Conga.Platform.Telemetry.Middlewares.TracingContextMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.BrowserRefreshMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication\u00601 application)"},"TraceId":"ad9347b6f8e328b9d9a734cdda74d19d","SpanId":"b95f01ffbbcc115d","TraceFlags":0}

Comment: Post the exception please

Comment: @Zinov Added in the post

Comment: The inner exception should give more info. Likely a collision of identifiers

Comment: Yes, I suspect the same thing. I've complex properties with similar names in different classes and they are conflicting. How can I resolve this?

Comment: swaggerGenOptions.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName); helped